# RegExp Test with two variables : possible ?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use the Test() Method like I did here :

```
var namealbum = data.data[i].name;
var text = namealbum;

if (/les comics d/i.test(text) == false) {
            //do nothing
        } else {

        var albumid = data.data[i].id;
            $('body').append('<section id="album album'+j+'"><h2 id="album_title">'+text+'</h2><div id="images"></div></section>');
```

But I wonder if it's possible to use this method with two variables.

Kind of like this :

```
var comicname = photos.data[i].name;
var comicpicture= photos.data[i].source;
var comiclink = photos.data[i].link;


    if (albumid.test(comiclink) == false){
    }else {
      $('#images').append('<img src="'+comicpicture+'"/>');
    };
```

Actually, I want to test if there is the content of the variable *albumid* (which is the ID of an album) in the link of a photograph stored in the variable *comiclink*.

I hope you guys will understand my bad english.

Thank you though !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there is no need to use a regex, You can [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) like

```
if (comiclink.toLowerCase().indexOf(albumid.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
```

---

If you still want to use a regex

```
//on page load
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}



var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(albumid), 'i');
if (regex.test(comiclink) == false) {} else {
    $('#images').append('<img src="' + comicpicture + '"/>');
};
```